# is it possible to get customized pdf report from oracle database?

Tags: python, oracle, pdf, report

I am a python developer using zope server with oracle db.. we generate reports using python web application using reportlab. But now a days report generation taking much time.So i thought to take reports directly from oracle itself is there any way. Thanks..

Comment: have you thought about profiling your current code and figuring out exactly where it slows down?

Comment: Have you had a look at the `explain plan` of your query?